# How to stop my bold/italic/underline options changing the text's font back to the default font and size

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox, richtext, rich-text-editor

In my application, I have a feature that allows the user to change the bold/italic/underline styles of the text. However, I have noticed that when the user makes the text bold, it reverts the text to the default size and font and THEN makes it bold. Obviously this is undesired as it would then mean that the user would have to change the font and size of the text again, which is undesirable.

Currently, the code for making the text bold within my application's richtextbox is:

```
richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Font,
            richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionFont.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);
```

Where am I going wrong? It does make the text bold, but it reverts the text back to the default size and font... However, the colour is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the sample code provided by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.RICHTEXTBOX.SELECTIONFONT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

```
  System.Drawing.Font currentFont = richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionFont;
  System.Drawing.FontStyle newFontStyle;

  if (richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionFont.Bold == true)
  {
     newFontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
  }
  else
  {
     newFontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
  }

  richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionFont = new Font(
     currentFont.FontFamily, 
     currentFont.Size, 
     newFontStyle
  );
```

**Edit**

As per @abalter suggestion I put inside this answer the sample code I write in a comment below. That code probably better match what asked in the question.

```
if (richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionFont.Bold == true)
{
    newFontStyle = currentFont.Style ^ FontStyle.Regular;
}
else
{
    newFontStyle = currentFont.Style | FontStyle.Bold;
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the code sample. I've tried this, but the only issue now is that I can't have two different styles (say bold and underline) at once. I've changed the rest to this code and modified it to replace "Bold" with italic/underline/strikeout. Any advice?

Comment: On [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DRAWING.FONTSTYLE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) it says that "FontStyle enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values."  When you create the "newFontStyle" object, try a combination of needed FontStyle: `newFontStyle = FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic`

Comment: @Spaceman -- post that code as an answer so I can upvote it and the OP can accept it.  If you don't, I will ;)

Comment: @abalter: I edited my original answer to include the code written in the comment. Thanks for the suggestion ;)